# Nodejs express render not working with ejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using express ejs on my node server to render views in a multiview app. On the client side, I'm using Angularjs. The initial view is a login page, which is getting displayed correctly when using `res.render('pages/login')`. I want to render a new view when user successfully connects, but for the next `res.render('pages/home')`, it stays on the login page, although I'm receiving correct HTML on client side.
Here's my relative code:

> partial file structure :

```
   App
     public/js/Script.js
     views/pages
          login.ejs
          home.ejs
     server.js
```

> server.js

```
...
app.get('/',function(req, res){
   res.render('pages/login'); //being displayed
});

app.get('/rest/home',function(req, res){
   res.render('pages/home'); //not being displayed
});
app.post('/login',function(req, res){
   //authentification
});
...
```

> Script.js

```
.controller ('loginController', function ($scope, $http) {     
   $scope.authent = function(){
      $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: '/login',
         data: $.param($scope.loginData),
         headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      }).success(function(res){
         $scope.launch();
      });
   $scope.launch = function(){
      $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: '/rest/home',
      }).success(function(res){
         alert(res); //Here, I am getting the content of home.ejs, but the view doesn't load in browser
      });     
   };      
})
.controller ('homeController', function () {
});
```

> login.ejs

```
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
       ...
</head>
<body  ng-controller="loginController">
    <div id="loginView">
       <form name="login" id="login" ng-submit="authent()">
          <input id="login_id" name="login_id" type="text" ng-model="loginData.loginId"/> 
          <input id="password" name="password" type="password" ng-model="loginData.password"/>
          <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Login"/>
       </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> home.ejs

```
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
   ...
</head>
<body  ng-controller="homeController">
   <h1>Home</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

It's my first time using ejs with angularjs and I'm not quite sure of my approach, so any suggestions for a better approach are also welcomed. I've tried using Route, but not very satisfied.
I hope I am clear with my explanation.

Comment: You should learn a bit more about routing and how views work in angular. Check $routeProvider and ng-view. Your views for angular should be in public folder unless you need to prerender some dynamic data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I used `$routeProvider`. Here's the solution :

File Structure :

```
App
  /public/js/Script.js
  /views/
       layout.ejs
       /partials/
          login.ejs
          home.ejs
  /routes/
       index.js
  server.js
```

server.js

```
...
var engine = require('ejs-locals');
var routes = require('./routes');
app.engine('ejs', engine);

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');    
app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);
app.get('/', routes.index); //Important to place this last
...
```

index.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
   res.render('layout');
};

exports.partials = function (req, res) {
   var name = req.params.name;
   res.render('partials/' + name);
};
```

script.js

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
         templateUrl : 'partials/login',
         controller  : 'loginController'
      })
      .when('/home', {
         templateUrl : 'partials/home',
         controller  : 'homeController'
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo: "/"});
})
app.controller ('loginController', function ($scope, $http) {     
  ...
   $scope.launch = function(){
      $http({
         ...
      }).success(function(res){
         $location.path('/home');  
      });     
   };      
})
```

layout.ejs

```
...
<body>
   ...
   <div ng-view></div> <!-- This section will be replaced with rendered view -->
   ...
</body>
...
```